# Expressions of Class in python

Tags: python

In one of our homework problems, we need to write a class in python called Gate which contains the drawing and function of many different gates in a circuit. It describes as follows:

```
in1 = Gate("input")
out1 = Gate("output")
not1 = Gate("not")
```

Here `in1`, `out1`, `not1` are all instances of this class. What do the `("input")` `("output")` `("not")` mean? are they subclass or something?
We are only told that when we define a class using:

```
class Gate(object)
```

when we make an instance we use:

```
in1 = Gate()
```

I haven't seen stuff inside a () after the class name, how to understand that?

Comment: You're creating *instances*, and passing an `__init__` parameter to each one.

Comment: Thank you!@jonrsharpe I realized later. One more question, when I later used

Comment: Go read about "inheritance"

Comment: in1.inputValues: is this"inputValues" an attribute defined in the __init__?in1.getInputGates(): is this "getInputGates()" an method defined in the functions inside the Gate class?

Comment: I guess, but given that you must have the definition *why don't you just look?*

Comment: Common work on it and laugh on this question after 2-3 month .

Answer (score 0):

> What is `in1 = Gate("input")` this?

In short this `Gate("input")` is a constructor call `def init`.

Use for create object.
`Gate()` and `Gate("some value")` both are constructor but

1). `Gate()` Create a object without initialize value to particular attributes of this object.

2). `Gate('some value')` Create a object with a value.

And i think you need to work on some basic concept of OOPS.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that you pass strings as a parameter I would suggest that it is just a parameter like:

```
class Gate:
    def __init__(self, param1):
        self.param1 = param1

var1 = Gate("hello")

print var1.param1
# expected output:
# hello
```

To be able to say how the class Gate works one has to look into it.